# $U_1(1) \times U_2(1) \rightarrow U_1(1), U_2(1)$ Particle decay

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Suppose a hypothetical (Dirac-)particle having two U(1) gauge symmetries, i.e two electromagnetic type interactions of the form $U_1(1) \times U_2(1)$. Which interaction Hamiltonian could lead to a  decay of this particle into two separate particles having $U_i(1)$ symmetries each?

The 'standard' interaction
$H_{int} = \sum_i q_i j_i^{\mu}A_{\mu,i} + j_{12}^{\mu}\sum_i q_i A_{\mu,i}$
(where $j_{12}$ labels the current carrying both charges and $i=1,2$) does not allow for such a decay.

To be more specific: Assume the Lagrangian

$\mathcal{L}_{1,2,(12)} = \sum_{n=1,2,(12)} \bar\psi_n (i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m_n) \psi_n - \sum_{i=1,2}\frac{1}{4} F_{i,\mu\nu} F_i^{\mu\nu} -\sum_{i=1,2} q_i j_i^{\mu}A_{\mu,i} - j_{12}^{\mu}\sum_{i=1,2} q_i A_{\mu,i}$

where $\psi_i$ has $U_i(1)$ symmetry and $\psi_{12}$ has $U_1(1) \times U_2(1)$ symmetry. Furthermore, $j_i^{\mu} = \bar\psi_i \gamma^\mu \psi_i$ and $j_{12}^{\mu} := \bar\psi_{12} \gamma^\mu \psi_{12}$.  Is the particle $a_{12}^{*}(m_{12}, 0) |0\rangle $ stable? (i.e a 12 particle at rest). If yes, in which theory/Lagrangian would it decay?

I guess that the particle is stable, mainly since I can't see a decay channel (charge is conserved at any vertex) but the fact that I cannot figure out a corresponding Feynman-diagram does not prove anything..

Comment: What do you mean by "circumstances" here? The possible decays depend on your Lagrangian, without giving us the Lagrangian of this theory, the question is underspecified.

Comment: It will decay so that each charge, e for the first U(1), and e' for the second one, are conserved.

Comment: Your edit is baffling. Assume decay $\bar a a \to \gamma \gamma'\to \bar b b \bar c c $ where *a* couples to both *γ* types, but *b* to only *γ*  and *c* to only *γ'* .  Having written down the tree diagram, read off the interaction terms for your Lagrangian.

Comment: Hi alain. Welcome to Phys.SE. What is the field content of your theory?

Comment: Your $j^\mu _{12}$ is ill defined. One would think it should be $j^\mu_1+ cj^\mu_2$, but this is wrong, given its coupling to the two photons. You do know charged leptons in QED are absolutely stable, no? The only reason the muon decays is by virtue of its non-abelian couplings.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for the comments. I do not understand in how far the current $j_{12}^{\mu}$ is ill defined. My assumption is that the Lagrangian given above is formally correct (relativistic, gauge), describing a (hypothetical) 3 particle type system. If not, what would be a correct Lagrangian describing such a system? (Containing particles of charge type 1 and 2 and a particle type holding both charges, where all charge types are $U(1)$, no $SU(n)$ type charges)

Comment: SU(n)? But you posited strictly U(1)xU(1). Your cross-current should be a direct sum structure. Write it down explicitly.

Comment: There are _no_ $SU(n)$ like interactions, the cross current is  defined as $j_{12}^{\mu} = \bar \psi_{12} \gamma^{\mu} \psi_{12}$.

Comment: Oh, you used a nastily *nonstandard* definition of the symmetry current. What you call cross-current is a linear combination of pieces belonging to the two $j^\mu_i$s.  If the fermions all talk to abelian photons, obviously they are stable, as written, just like the electron in QED. I showed you how their Onia decay. If you want the fermions to decay themselves,   to a fermion and a boson, say, couple them directly by an invariant term under both your U(1)s. Why do you bother with the photons at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gauge interactions here is a red herring. You don’t have a decay in your example because there are no suitable coupling terms. An obvious way to fix this sort of thing:

Take
$$  \psi_{12} \mapsto e^{i\alpha_1+i\alpha_2}\psi_{12} \\
 \psi_{1} \mapsto e^{i\alpha_1}\psi_{1} \\
  \phi_{2} \mapsto e^{i\alpha_2}\phi_{2},
$$
with $m_{12}> m_1 + m_2$, and $\phi_2$ a scalar with the suitable kinetic and mass terms added, and, if desired, photon 1 and 2 couplings. The currents are obviously unaffected.

You'd get a decay by a (globally symmetric)  Yukawa term,
$$
g \bar\psi_{12} \phi_2 \psi_1 + g \bar\psi_{1} \phi_2^* ~\psi_{12},
$$
so
$$
 \psi_{12} \to \phi_2 \psi_1 
$$
can go, preserving all symmetries and statistics (can't expect the fermion to go to two fermions).

Of course, as commented, a $\bar\psi_{12}\psi_{12}$ onium would decay to $\bar\psi_1\psi_1$ and $\phi^*_2 \phi_2$ by emission of one γ of each kind, as well.